# Android How to handle Touchevent in OpenGL Thread efficiently?

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, touch-event

I handle my onTouchEvent like this:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
   queueEvent(new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
         mRenderer.onTouchEvent(event);
      }
   });
   return true;
}
```

I have to queue the call into my GL Thread because I want to update most of the stuff only if the user touches and game related stuff changes.

However the queueEvent solution seems to be a bit slow. It takes 10-15ms between the onTouchEvent at the MainActivity and the onTouchEvent at my Renderer. Is it possible to achieve lower delays without passing the onTouchEvent directly?

Comment: I don't know if this will help but I had to move my onTouchEvent out of the GLSurfaceView into the MainActivity. Also, return true allows for drag events and false for no handling of drag events.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it this way, 10-15 ms means that you will be able to draw the next frame from the current user input. At 60fps (android default), it's 16 ms between each frame. It has to synchronize the input with the renderer and it cannot interfere at any time. Of course, you could change values inside the renderer in a synchronized way, but still, it can be only drawn in the next frame, which might take about that much time too.